# How did Yoda react to the destruction of Alderaan?

Tags: star-wars, a-new-hope, death-star, yoda

If Obi-Wan can feel the strong disturbance in the Force from the destruction of Alderaan by the Death Star, wouldn't Yoda have felt it too? After all, he felt the fall of the Jedi throughout the galaxy during the execution of Order 66.

So did Yoda feel it? And how did he react to it?

Comment: "A great disturbance in the force, I felt:  as if cried out in terror millions of voices did, and suddenly silenced, they were.  Something terrible, I fear happened has."

Comment: Yoda lashed out with the Force in rage and agony at Alderaan's loss, laying waste to Dagobah and its two billion inhabitants.  That's why Yoda lied to Luke about everything, to keep off him balance so he'd not think to wonder why his flight computer even knew how to get to a sucking mudhole like Dagobah.

Comment: I think there is no answer possible with canon and no canon here. But speculation that is.

Comment: I think it drove him mad with grief. Literally.

Comment: Destroyed alderan is, sad I am

Answer (score 5):

As there is to my knowledge no direct possible answer here (canon and non canon), we need to delve into speculation.

Obi wan was quite near when he felt the death of Alderaan. So it could be that you need to be nearby to feel it. But Yoda on the other hand proved in *Revenge of the Sith* that death can be felt half a galaxy away. He felt the death of the Jedi masters which in turn saved his life as he was wary because of that.

So as Yoda could feel the death of single individuals strong in the force it is very possible that he felt the death of billions of people at the same time (as even Obi Wan could feel that despite being less attuned to the force than Yoda as is proven by *Revenge of the Sith* again as only Yoda felt the death of the Jedi masters).

With that said though Yoda's reaction can only be pure speculation. Very probably feelings of regret and sorrow being there but he knew because of his encounter with Palpatine that he could do nothing. Nothing but wait for the new hope to surface and fulfill the will of the force that is.

Answer (score 2):

According to the (canon) story [There is Another](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/There_is_Another), **Yoda was unaware of the fate of Alderaan**. Although we can't be entirely certain of the timeline, at approximately the point that Obi-Wan was on board the Falcon (and when Alderaan was destroyed), Yoda was mainly concerned with moving house and remembering to bring seeds for planting season. These are hardly the acts of someone who'd detected a massive change in the Force.

> Yoda stood at the door of his hut, watching the straight streaks of sunlight tear apart the gathered gray of the sky.
>   He turned and looked inside.
>   Then back to the sky.
>   It was time. Probably past time. The rains had ended more than half an orbit before. Soon the sun would bear down upon Dagobah and the uplands would be too hot for even a small one like himself to bear. He had maybe a few days. Maybe less.
>   He sighed. Of the two seasons on Dagobah, the dry was the one he preferred. The view from the uplands reminded him of…a time and place from long ago. But by now the lower lands would have drained some, and the trees would have begun to emerge from their watery covering. It would soon be time to plant in the soggy reaches.
>   Planting was a bother, but even a Jedi Master needs to eat.

Note that he ***does*** detect the fight between Anakin and Obi-Wan a few hours later, describing it as being on the very edge of his capacity to sense.

> Then, **he felt something on the very edge of his reach.**
>   And he was out in the open.
>   This is what comes of not keeping your mind on where you are and what you are doing!